# webjars for angularjs Failed to Load 404 in Weblogic, which is working in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, weblogic-10.x, webjars

I am trying to migrate application from Tomcat to Weblogic. I am using Spring , Hibernate and build tool.
I could able deploy and login , but from Home page , it is not loading because of Angular JS is not loaded. It was working good in Tomcat, but in Weblogic 10.3.6, I could able to figure it out.

**POM.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/jquery/**" location="/jquery/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/jqueryui/**" location="/jqueryui/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/includes/**" location="/includes/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/pages/**" location="/pages/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/views/**" location="/views/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/modals/**" location="/modals/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/icons/**" location="/icons/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/bootstrap/**" location="/bootstrap/"/>
```

I am not sure about what to add in weblogic.xml.

Please Note : Using Servlet 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong. perhaps I'm in the wrong file. Where does this line get placed? I have it in my spring-config.xml file and it keeps saying it can't resolve the location.

Comment: @FateNuller What is the entire error?  What version of Spring?

Comment: @JamesWard Does this setting mean, that requests to `"/webjars/**"` should be mapped to `"classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"`? If so, how do webjars get located at that place? Why that place, not another? Is it set somewhere else?

Comment: WebJars always have their files under `/META-INF/resources/webjars` and as long as you have a WebJar on your CLASSPATH its contents will be available via the classloader at that path.